# Dockerfile for Gluster... Can't get the service to start when the container is created

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, dockerfile, glusterfs

[Current dockerfile](https://github.com/GoingOffRoading/GlusterFS/blob/main/GlusterFS-Server/dockerfile):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:gluster/glusterfs-9 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y glusterfs-server

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Using this, the container starts perfectly...  However the service being installed (Gluster) doesn't start.

I've tried combinations of RUN, CMD, & ENTRYPOINT scripts executing variations of "service glusterd start" (the command  to start the Gluster daemon) but those combinations:

- Cause the container to exit on creation
- Cause errors that crash the container

I can confirm "service glusterd start" is the correct command that needs to be run, as:

- I can SSH into the running container/pod
- Confirm that the Gluster daemon is not running
- Run "service glusterd start" in the container/pod without errors
- Confirm  that the Gluster daemon has started after running "service glusterd start"

Any ideas on how to execute "service glusterd start" at the container creation in the dockerfile?

Comment: As a general rule, commands like `service` or `systemctl` just don't work in Docker.  Can you set your `CMD` to run the daemon as a foreground process, without the init-system wrapper?

Comment: @DavidMaze There is an option for this with the Glusterd daemon...  "glusterd -N": https://linux.die.net/man/8/glusterd    A weird issue is that when I do what you described,  the container hangs on this step when I build the container image.  I'll try this again this afternoon and will report back.

Comment: @DavidMaze You were right on the money.  It took some tweaking but everything is working: https://github.com/GoingOffRoading/GlusterFS/blob/main/GlusterFS-Server/dockerfile

I'm going to post the answer for anybody that finds this post in the future.

I'd much rather give you credit for the answer if you want to "answer" the post bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real credit goes to DaveMaze in the comments... His note about service/systemctl and CMD lead me down a path that ended up working:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:gluster/glusterfs-9 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y glusterfs-server

CMD glusterd -N
```

Works perfectly.